# Drupal Exposed Views Filter custom date

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a date filter that I have exposed on my view. I want to make the interface more user friendly and tighten up the look of it. Instead of selecting a date I would like to select from the following options.

- The last day
- The last week
- The last year
- All

This would then filter on the date field. Is this possible? How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 6):

The proper way to do it is to alter the form in a custom module using [`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter):

```
function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    $view = &$form_state['view'];
    $display = &$form_state['display'];
    if ($view->name == 'YOURVIEWNAME' && $display->id == 'YOURDISPLAYID') {
      //Alter $form here, use dpm($form) to inspect it.
    }
  }
}
```

`$form` is an array describing the form, using Drupal [Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/group/form_api/6). You can inspect this array using [`dpm`](http://api.lullabot.com/dpm) from the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module.

Answer (score 0):

It is possbile, but you will need to write your own module for that.

That module would use the method called "Form Alter" to change the form. Try starting here http://drupal.org/node/157253