# Multiple filter criteria in one exposed filter

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-exposed-filter

I'm trying to create a view with two exposed filters, one for category and one for time. I got the category done ([read about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183927/behance-like-content-filter-possible-in-drupal)), but I can't get the time filter to work.

My idea is to make an exposed filter with 4 different dates in (all, day, week and month).
At the moment I've made 4 different "Content: Post Date" with different times (<= +1 day and so on) that I want to put in an exposed filter so when I use it, I can only choose **one** of the 4 different filters from a list (like I've done with the categories).

So the question is: **How do I put multiple filter criterias into one exposed filter?**
or **Is there a better way to do this?**

Best regards,
Alexandberg

Edit:

Found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049334/drupal-exposed-views-filter-custom-date) where someone got a similar problem to me, but the thing is that I don't really understand what to do with the code in the answer. It says that I need to put the `hook_form_alter` in a custom module, but some help with that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the new Grouped Filter functionality in Views 3.5. It allows you to do exactly what you're looking for.